# Creation of box at edge of the Knode using KLighD

Tags: xtend, eclipse-elk

In `Klighd` I am trying to create the following :

[image]

Where the BOX-A is a KNode and BOX-C I have made as KPort. For BOX-B I am creating it as child Knodes of BOX-A. But the issue is coming while creating BOX-B at the edge of Knode A. if I make it as a child Knode and place it at the edge by using setGridPlacementData() then all the child Knodes are placed at the edge but I need these particular boxes to be there. Is there any way to restrict other boxes to go to the edge or any other way we can make this boxes.

I tried to make BOX-B as the child Knodes for the Knode Box-A but it will not work as all the Child knodes are going to the edge. ijust need some particular knodes to go to the edge rest can be placed in the middle of the Box-A.